# Pbcopy sort of freezes (I can still type though)

Tags: terminal

If I use pbcopy on a small file, string or just run it, it doesn't do anything. Just gives me a blinking cursor. I am still able to type something but can only exit using ctrl-c. Is anyone familiar with this? Am I doing something wrong? What can I try/do to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I think of pbcopy as a pipe-sink and then the behavior of `pbcopy` and `xclip` match perfectly. They take data though std input and put it in clipboard.

```bsh
# With pbcopy
cat file_name | pbcopy
echo "Stuff, copied via tmux/vim internal buffer" | pbcopy

# With xclip
cat file_name | xclip -selection clipboard
echo "Yeah, vim,tmux can copy directly into clipboard buffer" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

`<<<` is just a input redirection (special case of `<<`) and by this thought process, it becomes easier to use since the following are equivalent

```
echo Hi | sink
sink <<< Hi
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. Commands like this dont work:

```
pbcopy hey
```

But it seems like this does work:

```
pbcopy <<< hey
```